# Swift Ошибка - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: php, swift

Я только учусь по этому прошу помочь.

Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

Код Swift:

```
 @IBAction func userSaveInfoButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let userName = userNameTextField.text!
        let userAge = userAgeTextField.text!
        let userPhone = userPhoneTextFIeld.text!
        let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text!
        let userInteres = userInteresTextFIeld.text!
        let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text!
        let oblojka = self.userBG.image!
        let avatar = self.userAva.image!
        let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("ID") as? String

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/userProfile.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let posting = "id=\(id)nameuser=\(userName)&age=\(userAge)&password=\(userPassword)&email=\(userEmail)&phone=\(userPhone)&interes=\(userInteres)"
         request.HTTPBody = posting.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }


            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {
                    print("Ошибка тут 2")
                    let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
                    print(resultValue)
                    self.myImageUploadRequestAva()
                    self.displayMyAlertMessage("Данные были успешно изменены!")
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }


        }

        task.resume()

    }
```

Код PHP:

```
<?php

require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");


if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = htmlentities($email);
}
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $password = htmlentities($password);
}
if(isset($_POST['age'])){
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $age = htmlentities($age);
}
if(isset($_POST['phone'])){
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $phone = htmlentities($phone);  
}

if(isset($_POST['interes'])){
    $interes = $_POST["interes"];
    $interes = htmlentities($interes);
}
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $id = htmlentities($id);
}
if(isset($_POST['nameuser'])){
    $name = $_POST["nameuser"];
    $name = htmlentities($name);
}

if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
}


if(isset($_POST['photo'])){
    $photo = $_POST["photo"];
    $photo = "/img/'".$photo."'";

    $target_dir = "/img/";

    $uploaddir = dirname(getcwd()).'/img/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo json_encode([
            "Message" => "The file ". basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
            "Status" => "OK"
        ]);
    } 
    else {
         $oblojka = "/img/noava.jpg";
    }
}

else {
    $photo = "/img/noava.png";
}

if(isset($_POST['oblojka'])){
    $oblojka = $_POST["oblojka"];
    $oblojka = "/img/'".$oblojka."'";

    $uploaddir = dirname(getcwd()).'/img/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo json_encode([
            "Message" => "The file ". basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
            "Status" => "OK"
        ]);
    } else {
       $oblojka = "/img/avapepsi.jpg";
    }

} else {
    $oblojka = "/img/avapepsi.jpg";
}


$returnValue = array();

$secure_password = $password;

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userProfile = $dao->updateProfile($id,$photo,$oblojka,$name,$email,$secure_password,$interes,$phone,$age);

if(!empty($userProfile)){
    $returnValue["status"] = "Success";
    $returnValue["message"] = "User is update";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
} 
else {
    $returnValue["status"] = "error";
    $returnValue["message"] = "User is not update";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
}

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ошибку

> let posting =
>   "id=(userId)**&**nameuser=(userName)&age=(userAge)&password=(userPassword)&email=(userEmail)&phone=(userPhone)&interes=(userInteres)"